# What is the name of this ivy?

Tags: identification, vines

[image: Picture]

I have this ivy growing, but would like to know the exact species.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Hedera helix 'sagittifolia', see the image below:

[image: Hedera helix 'SAGITTIFOLIA']

[Hedera helix 'SAGITTIFOLIA'](http://www.havlis.cz/karta_en.php?kytkaid=509)

It's hardy down to USDA zone 6 outdoors, but you're obviously growing it as a houseplant - it's a relatively slow growing variety and doesn't need sun exposure.